# Drawing a square in the center of a canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a Square within my `onDraw` method in Android.

1. The square must be positioned in the exact center of the canvas
   (Not the screen)
2. The padding/spacing on the left and right hand side of the square should be
   equal
3. The padding/spacing on the top and bottom of the square should be equal
4. The size of the square should be relatively large, about 90% of the
   canvas's width

Here's what I have so far.

```
//this.rect is an instance of Rect() which later gets called in the canvas.drawRect() method
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
    int padding = (width / 10);

    this.size = width - padding;
    this.rect.set(padding,padding,size,size);

}
```

The code above draws the square but I'm not sure how to get it to center in the canvas. I am also open to using another technique that does not involve using a `Rect`.

What properties do I need to set to this `Rect()` in order for the `canvas.drawRect(rect,paint)` to draw the rectangle directly in the center of the canvas?

Edit:
[Terribly drawn example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmXJK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `width` is the width of the canvas, I guess you're missing substracting the padding twice.-

```
this.size = width - padding * 2;
```

**EDIT**

Since we're talking about a rectangle here, you'll need to do some more changes to your code, and calculate different top and left padding .-

```
int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
int paddingLeft = (width / 10);
size = width - paddingLeft * 2;
int paddingTop = (height - size) / 2;
this.rect.set(paddingLeft,paddingTop,size,size);
```

**EDIT 2**

Maybe a clearer approach would start calculating the size of your square.-

```
size = width * 0.9f;
int paddingLeft = (width - size) / 2;
int paddingTop = (height - size) / 2;
this.rect.set(paddingLeft,paddingTop,size,size);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The canvas itself is not in the shape of a square. My original code is a class that extends View.

Comment: I see... then you need to calculate both width and height, let me update my answer...

Comment: I've updated the OP with an image reflecting what I'm trying to achieve.